# Пропорциональная картинка в div'e и позиционирование элемента

Tags: html, css

Есть один макет:

https://pp.vk.me/c619131/v619131689/16c67/IhRbAtHH_jU.jpg

У меня получилось его сделать так:

https://pp.vk.me/c619131/v619131689/16c60/ZMkYK0T7qi8.jpg

[Вот примерный код](http://jsfiddle.net/f8thv87e/1/)

В первую очередь меня интересует: как сделать обводку для h2 круглой и чтобы элемент был в центре, а не как на моей картинке?

Потом мне интересно, как пропорционально растянуть картинку на весь `div.item-body`?

На данный момент я задал высоту и ширину 100%, и результат очень огорчает.

Comment: @S_G, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

P.S.: Вот вам бонус: http://jsfiddle.net/qyjhdroo/1/embedded/result/

Answer (score 2):

h2: задайте border-radius, padding.

Картинку сделайте фоном и используйте background-size. Или уберите принудительное задание высоты у картинки и поставьте диву overflow соответственно.

P.S. То, что я вижу в фиддле, меня огорчает.

Comment: >P.S. То, что я вижу в фиддле, меня огорчает.

Ну там еще пара бутстраповских класса смягчают обстоятельства, а так и меня это огорчает)

Comment: @S_G, все просто. Картинка будет лежать как `background-image`, что бы она подходила и вписывалась в блок - дайте ему `background-size: cover||contain`. Что бы разместить блок в центре уже созданного-блока картинки дайте ему ширину и высоту. После этого можно использовать трюк: `top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-top: -заданная высота/2; margin-left: -заданная ширина/2`. Для того что бы сделать цифру читабельней дайте padding, для того что бы верстка не полезла дайте `box-sizing: border-box`, для того что бы она была круглой дайте картинке `border-radius: 50%`.

Comment: @S_G, По сути посмотрите решение мсье FallenMaster и добавьте туда мое описание. Шик!

Answer (score 1):

```css
.item-size { 
  height: 25%;
  float: center;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left: 15px;
  }

.item-body {
  background-image: url('https://xaroktet.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/kvadrat-golova.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 15px;  
  position:relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  }
.item-body div{
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 18px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  }
.item-heading{
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="panel panel-default item-size">
  <div class="item-body">
    <div>13</div>      
  </div>
  <div class="item-heading">Обана!</div>
</div>
```